# Can't Run program beyond a certain point using modules

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, module, attributeerror

In my terminal emulator I'm working on, I have 3 different modules, as well as the main program. One that prints text as if it was being typed, one to clear the screen, and one that offers simple terminal commands like ls and cd.

I had modified the terminal commands module so that it would have the delay between each character appearing  on the screen, using the aforementioned typing module. It worked as it was intended, but when I would try to import both module into the main script, It appears to run fine, up until the terminal commands module is called, where it throws a undefined function. Then, if in both, I would get an error stating there was no typingPrint attribute in the typing module, when there is.

I tried to remove the import statement for the typing module from the terminal command module, and I get an error stating that typing is not defined, but then if I try removing typing from the main script and re-adding the import statement to the terminal command module, I get the same thing
If both the main script and the terminal command module have the typing module imported, then an AttributeError, which I thought was a circular import error, but it wasnt.

Typing Module import statement:

```
import time, sys, colorama, random
from colorama import Fore, init, Back, Style
from os import system, name
```

Terminal command (fileModification) import statement:

```
import os, shutil, typing
```

Main script import statement:

```
import time, sys, shutil, random
from Lib import typing, clear, fileModification
```

Edit: If I revert the whole script to not use the delay, it works fine. The only error I was getting was that there was supposedly not an attribute for the typing module.

Comment: probably need to see more of the code, enough to run and test. Could be any number of things like incorrect calling of a function or namespace clashes, etc.

Comment: @DevinCeartas Easiest way is probobly going to be to share the repo link, so https://github.com/Jaxer6563/FO4-Terminal-Emulator . I already know the structuring is horrible, Im just trying to get it put together, and then work on optimizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues, both related to the import statement of the `fileModification` module.

The first issue is that Python has a built-in module called `typing`. Hence, when you import `typing` in the `fileModification` module, Python imports the built-in version, not your version.

However, the second, deeper issue is that even if you had used a non-ambiguous name for your `typing` module, the import would still fail because you did not specify the correct path to fetch your custom `typing` module. In other words, you will not reach `Lib.typing` from the `fileModification` module just by `import typing`.

To resolve the issue, you can change the import statements of your `fileModification` module to

```py
import os, shutil
from Lib import typing
```

But better yet, I'd recommend you change the name of your `typing` module to something less ambiguous.

Comment: Would I need to put my `typing` module in a new Lib folder within the folder that all my modules are stored in? They are all contained in a single Lib directory, direectly below the main directory of the program

Comment: No need to put your `typing` module in a new folder. You can put all your modules under the same `Lib` folder, but make sure to include this folder in the import statement.